# Call source from inside a Go program

Tags: go

For fun and to better learn Go, I'm trying to re-implement antigen in Go.

Problem is: `source` is a shell built-in function, so I can't call it with `os/exec` `Command` function, because it expects an executable in `PATH`.

How can I do this? And, is it possible to make a `source` from inside a go program affect the user shell?

Comment: Even if you could call "source", you can't change the parent process environment. Exactly what effect are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Sad :/ Antigen is a plugin manager for ZSH... so, basically, it git pulls repositories and source the *.plugin.zsh file...

Comment: What's sad? That's just how shells work. The whole point of antigen is to execute shell code in your shell.

Comment: Yeah, but it's slow. I hacked it a little, and got a "simplified" version working 5 times faster than antigen does: https://github.com/caarlos0/antibody

Comment: If theres real work that could be sped up with Go (I haven't read through the code at all), you could output the final variables, function defs, etc. you need on stdout, and wrap the Go command in an `eval`.

Comment: Yeah, that's basically what I did :) thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write the command directly in the terminal device. But, to do that, first you need to know which device is using the user.  A script that executes your program can be a solution.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Running from foo script, pid = $$
go run foo.go `tty`
```

Then, the program has to write the commands to the terminal device.

```
package main

import (
    "C"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "syscall"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    // Get tty path
    if len(os.Args) < 2 {
        fmt.Printf("no tty path\n")
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    ttyPath := os.Args[1]

    // Open tty
    tty, err := os.Open(ttyPath)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error opening tty: %s\n", err.Error())
        os.Exit(2)
    }
    defer tty.Close()

    // Write a command
    cmd := "echo Hello from go, pid = $$\n"
    cmdstr := C.CString(cmd)
    cmdaddr := uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(cmdstr))
    for i := range []byte(cmd) {
        _, _, err := syscall.Syscall(syscall.SYS_IOCTL, tty.Fd(), syscall.TIOCSTI, cmdaddr+uintptr(i))
        if uintptr(err) != 0 {
            fmt.Printf("syscall error: %s\n", err.Error())
            os.Exit(3)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is an example output:

```
$ echo $$
70318
$ ./foo 
Running from foo script, pid = 83035
echo Hello from go, pid = $$
$ echo Hello from go, pid = $$
Hello from go, pid = 70318
```

Note that I am executing the script with `./` not `source`, so the PID of the script differs. But later, the command executed by the go program has the same PID.

Comment: While an interesting hack,  your example doesn't work on any of the systems I tried (I think the input queue needs to be flushed, all I'm getting is an `e`). But if you're wrapping this in a shell script, why not just output something that the shell can `eval`? Also, `fmt.Errorf` only creates an `error` value, it doesn't print anything.

Comment: @JimB Sorry, I have forgotten that `syscall.Syscall` function returns an error even when there is no error. Now it should work.

Comment: Oh, of course. I missed it too, even when I looked at errno == 0. Anyway, I'd still rather use stdout and `eval` if I had to do something along these lines.

Comment: Nice hack! I end up using a different approach. Thanks anyways!